# bash- conditional triangle error

Tags: bash

my task was to print whether the numbers given signify ISOSCELES,EQUILATERAL, or SCALENE triangle.
My code prints only ISOSCELES: Where's the error ?

```
#!/bin/bash
read a b c
if [ "$a" == "$b" ] && { [ "$b" = "$c" ] && [ "$c" = "$a" ]; }
then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
exit 1
elif [ "$a" == "$b" ] && { [ "$b" = "$c" ] || [ "$c" = "$a" ]; }
then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
elif ([[ "$a" != "$b" ]] && [[ "$b" != "$c" ]] && [[ "$c" != "$a" ]])
then
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Comment: What are you giving as input?

Comment: i am giving input : `6 6 6`

Comment: Use -eq to compare integers

Comment: @merlin2011 or use an arithmetic context `(( a == b ))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a strange mixture of `[`, `[[`, `=` and `==` in your script. If you are using bash, I would suggest that you instead use `(( ))` for all of your numerical comparisons. This creates an arithmetic context, so it also means that you don't need to use `$` to refer to your variables:

```
if (( a == b )) && (( b == c )) && (( c == a )); then echo "equilateral"
elif (( a != b )) && (( b != c )) && (( c != a )); then echo "scalene"
else echo "isoceles"
fi
```

The separate test for isosceles is unnecessary.

Comment: Are you separating the variables by commas in your input? It works for me when I manually assign `a=2; b=3; c=4`

Comment: `read`, as you have written it in your question, is expecting three numbers all on the same line, like `2 3 4`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just count the number of different numbers to get the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
read a b c
different=$(printf '%s\n' $a $b $c |
            sort -n                |
            uniq -c                |
            wc -l
         )

case $different in
    (1) echo EQUILITERAL ;;
    (2) echo ISOSCELES   ;;
    (3) echo SCALENE     ;;
esac
```

You should also verify the triangle inequality at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/bash
read a b c
sorted=$( printf '%s\n' $a $b $c | sort -n )
ineq=${sorted/$'\n'/+}
ineq=${ineq/$'\n'/>}
(( $ineq )) || exit 1

different=$( uniq -c <<< "$sorted" | wc -l )

case $different in
    (1) echo EQUILITERAL ;;
    (2) echo ISOSCELES   ;;
    (3) echo SCALENE     ;;
esac
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning and handling the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

1. you mix `==` and `=` in your tests
2. change the order, first test for EQUILATERAL, then for SCALENE, then you don't need to test for ISOSCELES (*quartum non datur*;-)

Comment: Good point about changing the order around but you haven't indicated which of `=` and `==` you should be using. The answer, at least in `[` or `[[`, is neither, as you should be using `-eq` to compare numbers.

Comment: @TomFenech I haven't because I was sure other answers would have beaten the issue "Pacquiao-style" and, more important, much better than I could do. I do hope that you have appreciated the "quartum non datur", haven't you?

Comment: There is no harm in adding to your answer to make it more complete. As for your latin, very impressive, although personally I had to look it up!

Answer (score 0):

Try (use == or -eq for numbers):

```
   #!/bin/bash

   read a b c
   if [ "$a" == "$b" ] && { [ "$b" == "$c" ] && [ "$c" == "$a" ]; }
   then
      echo "EQUILATERAL"
  elif ([[ "$a" != "$b" ]] && [[ "$b" != "$c" ]] && [[ "$c" != "$a" ]])
  then
      echo "SCALENE"
  else
     echo "ISOSCELES"
  fi
```

Answer (score 0):

That a bit simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash
read a b c
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ] && [ "$b" -eq "$c" ] && [ "$c" -eq "$a" ];
then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
    exit 1
elif [ "$a" -ne "$b" ] && [ "$b" -ne "$c" ] && [ "$c" -ne "$a" ];
then
    echo "SCALENE"
else
    echo "ISOSCELES"
fi
```

I think thats the purposed output:

```
$ echo "6 6 6" | ./script
EQUILATERAL
$ echo "6 6 5" | ./script
ISOSCELES
$ echo "4 5 6" | ./script
SCALENE
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the sides of traingles as input using **read** command.

```
read a
read b
read c
if (( a == b )) && (( b == c )) && (( c == a )); 
then 
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif (( a != b )) && (( b != c )) && (( c != a ));
then 
    echo "SCALENE"
else 
    echo "ISOSCELES"
fi
```